# Changes in controller not showing on website Asp.net & iis

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this issue where i'm trying to publish a website while it build successfully, the publish fails and receives this error.

```
Copying file packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg to C:\Users\lecia.brown\AppData\Local\Temp\WebSitePublish\StudentRecordSystem--2062993544\obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.1.2.3.nupkg failed. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
```

**UPDATE**

The project was published before but now i'm trying to make changes to the website using visual studio and i'm not seeing the changes. i don't see what the issue could be. I have rebuild, delete teporay asp.net files and still no changes.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/234 - looks like you can point the temp publish path to something shorter which isn't a proper fix but at least a workaround

Comment: Is publishing the website allow me to see changes that I made in the controller?

Comment: You don't need to publish to see changes assuming you can debug and use IIS or the in-built IIS instance that comes with VS.

Comment: that's another issue i'm having i have made some changes to the controller and model and I'm not seeing the changes what could be the reason for that. I thought publishing it would solve that issue.\

Comment: Let's just clarify the terminology - publishing pushes the website to the host/disk/etc (the publish target). Running the project in Visual Studio will open whatever it is that you've set in your project settings - if that's a local IIS server, IIS express, console app running kestrel etc I can't tell you - but publishing is usually only done once you are finished with all your changes/have tested - it's essentially the "deploy to production environment" most of the time.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but this is a project that was published already and was given for me to make a change, however when I make the change it's not showing.

Comment: @Charleh, is it possible to tell me what's going on as to why i'm seeing the changes.

Comment: I keep getting the results of what was there before.